# How can I create a relative Url in a html link element for a web app running on IIS?

Tags: html, model-view-controller, iis, href

Let say I have a web application :

www.mymvcsite.com/MyVirtualDirectory/Controller/Action

In my view I have a `<a href="/FolderA/myfile.pdf">`.  Problem is the entire Html is coming from from a database!  Aha!  You thought this was as easy as @Url.Content()...  well that doesn't work cause the html is dynamic in fact I have no idea that there is even link element in the markup I'm blindly outputting it to the view.

So what do I need to put in the href in order for it to resolve the Url properly.

Ie.  "myfile.pdf" is located at... 
www.mymvcsite.com/MyVirtualDirectory/FolderA/myfile.pdf

BUT for some reason in the browser the url ends up being  
"www.mymvcsite.com/FolderA/myfile.pdf"

Note that the "MyVirtualDirectory" is missing!  I even tried adding a "~" to the Url but that doesn't work either.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the relative url in a hidden field:

```
<input id='hidPartialUrl' type='hidden' value='<%:ResolveUrl("~/") %>'/>
```

All links should be relative to the root of the site and have a common class name:

```
<a href='/FolderA/myfile.pdf' class='fixThisLink'>PDF</a>
```

Then when you load it into the page you do:

```
var hiddenHref = document.getElementById('hidPartialUrl').href;
var links = document.getElementsByClassName('fixThisLink'); 
for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].href = hiddenHref + links[i].href;
}
```

Set the href property on each one returned to include the first part of your url. I would store the first part of your url in a hidden field.

Comment: As per the question this is NOT a server-side question.  If it were that easy I'd use @Url.Content("~/FolderA/myfile.pdf").  HOWEVER, the html content is coming from the Database and the view does not know what the content is.

Comment: Ahh, well it looks like you are going to have to scrape the html with javascript and find the links.  You will then need to change the url with something you get from the server.  Can you put a css class on all the links you need to change?

Comment: I have full control over the Html content in the DB so I don't need to scrape it.  How do you suggest I use javascript to correct the url?  I imagine I could put that in place in the link itself.

Comment: I would have the link like <a href='/FolderA/myfile.pdf' class='fixThisLink'>PDF</a>

Then when you load it into the page you do: document.getElementsByClassName('fixThisLink'); and set the href property on each one returned to include the first part of your url.  I would store the first part of your url in a hidden field.

Comment: Thanks John that makes sense.  I went another route more inline with this http://iridescence.no/post/Resolving-relative-URLe28099s-from-JavaScript.aspx.  But if you post your solution as an answer I'll give you the points.